# Open a folder with File explorer using .bat

Tags: batch-file

What command should I use to open a specified path at the end of program.

```
start "c:\Yaya\yoyo\"
```

Is not working

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can try like this:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "c:\Yaya\yoyo\"
```

Comment: WOOOOOOOOORKING... How to open it in frontground?

Comment: Yaaap maan.. I am feeling love for u.. Bt see, its opening behind the cmd window. I want to bring the opened folder to the front.. Ok, forget I will try to manage it.. Thanks bro..

Comment: I have tried it a number of times. Bt, my low budget android is not supporting me, to support u..  I will sure do it, when am on my lappy..

Answer (score 26):

The start command needs `blank quotes` at the beginning, as it uses the first double quoted phrase as the `"Window title"`

```
start "" "c:\Yaya\yoyo\"
```

Comment: Note: this does **not** open a new Explorer window if one is already open to the target folder, instead one (the newest, I think) is brought to the front. This could be specifically desired behavior. If not, use the `explorer ...` option as @Dan suggested.

Answer (score 24):

I think it should be this:

```
explorer c:/Yaya/yoyo
```

Comment: `c:/Yaya/yoyo` will need quotes should the path contain spaces. `explorer "c:/Yaya/yoyo"`

Comment: Note: this opens a **new** Explorer window, even if one is already open to the target folder. This could be specifically desired behavior. If not, use the `start "" ...` option as @foxidrive suggested.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two examples to open folders, one in the location and the other with the folder selected in the parent directory.

```
:: Open an Explorer window with the 'temp' folder displayed and its parent hidden:
Explorer.exe /e,/root,"%temp%"

:: This one will open the parent directory and automatically select the 'temp' folder:
Explorer.exe /select,"%temp%"

:: See more examples here: https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html
```

#### See more examples here: https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html

Answer (score 4):

Open notepad and type

```
START C:\Yaya\yoyo\
```

Save as: filename.BAT

**Edit:** Some people have reported a string after the START keyword, wrapping the path inside double quotes is better as the path can have files/folder names with spaces.

```
 START "" "C:\Yaya\yoyo\"
```

In newer systems, For example, Windows 10 title is ignored because CMD opens and closes in the blink of any eye. The syntax for starting a new process is

**Syntax**

```
START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

Wherein

- title - Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
- path - Starting directory.
- command - The command, batch file or executable program to run.
- parameters - The parameters passed to the command.

Comment: How is this different from what the op tried? I've tried this in the latest OS and it does nothing. -1. The 'start` needs a `""` after it as @foxidrives' answer.

Comment: well somewhere it works with " ". I tried this one, it worked so I posted as an answer.

Comment: Just informing you it doesn't work. Also, the path will need to be wrapped in quotes too for filenames with spaces in.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1

```
start  "" "your directory or File"
```

eg:-

```
start  "" "E:\Code SAmple\"
```

[image]

Mehtod 2

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe  "your directory or File"
```

eg:-

```
 %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe  "E:\Code SAmple\"
```

[image]

Reference:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50266001/7706354

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20202906/7706354