# Open a folder using .bat

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, path, directory

What command should I use to open a specified Folder

these two lines are did not working

```
start   C:\xampp\htdocs\w\CodeIgniter_mysite\

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\w\CodeIgniter_mysite\
```

Comment: `C:\xampp\htdocs\w\CodeIgniter_mysite\index.php` is not a Folder. it is a file

Comment: I forgot :D  just " C:\xampp\htdocs\w\CodeIgniter_mysite\ "

Comment: With Windows 7, issuing  `explorer C:\Temp` or `explorer D:\Workspaces` on the command line works for me. Which version of Windows are you working on?

Comment: Version : windows 7

Comment: if you copy/paste that path into the start=>run dialog does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a folder with File explorer using .bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202880/open-a-folder-with-file-explorer-using-bat)

Answer (score 2):

```
explorer C:\xampp\htdocs\w\CodeIgniter_mysite\
```

Should Work

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax**

> explorer.exe [/n][/e][,/root,][[,/select],]

---

The command below works fine in Windows 10 for me:

```
explorer.exe /root,C:\
```

or in your case:

```
explorer.exe /root,C:\xampp\htdocs\w\CodeIgniter_mysite\
```

Don't forget the comma after the /root tag.

---

See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/130510) for more information on explorer.exe